# Unable to start PostgreSQL 12 Server

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgis, openstreetmap

I want to setup PostgreSQL 12 with PostGIS 3 on Ubuntu 20.04 for the purpose of creating an OSM Tile Server. I want to have 2 different clusters, one for a regular PSQL database and another for OSM data. I can't seem to get the one for the OSM data up and running:

When I run `pg_lsclusters`, I get the following:

```
Ver Cluster     Port Status Owner    Data directory                          Log file
12  main        5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main             /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
12  osm_psql_db 5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/2TB1/osm_psql_db /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-osm_psql_db.log
```

When I run `journalctl -xe`, I get the following:

```
Mar 13 11:47:37 cdil-MS-7B92 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for PostgreSQL Cluster 12-osm_psql_db.
-- Subject: A start job for unit postgresql@12-osm_psql_db.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit postgresql@12-osm_psql_db.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 9566 and the job result is dependency.
Mar 13 11:47:37 cdil-MS-7B92 systemd[1]: postgresql@12-osm_psql_db.service: Job postgresql@12-osm_psql_db.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar 13 11:47:37 cdil-MS-7B92 systemd[1]: var-lib-postgresql-12-osm_psql_db.mount: Job var-lib-postgresql-12-osm_psql_db.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar 13 11:47:37 cdil-MS-7B92 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-osm_psql_db.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-osm_psql_db.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Mar 13 11:47:43 cdil-MS-7B92 PackageKit[27900]: daemon quit
Mar 13 11:47:43 cdil-MS-7B92 systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit packagekit.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
```

Any idea what could be holding me up?

*** EXTRA INFO JUST IN CASE ***

In terms of how I set up everything, I installed the following packages:

```
sudo apt install postgresql-12 postgresql-contrib postgis postgresql-12-postgis-3
```

Because the OSM data is quite large, I want to store that particular cluster on another hard disk. It's called "2TB1" and it's been mounted to `/var/lib/postgresql/12/2TB1` because I realized that the postgres user needed access to the data_directory folder and all parent folders leading up to it.

To do so I modified the permissions of the new hard drive:

```
sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/2TB1
```

Next, I created the new db cluster instance:

```
sudo pg_createcluster 12 osm_psql_db -d /var/lib/postgresql/12/2TB1/osm_psql_db -p 5432
```

I start the new instance:

```
sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 osm_psql_db start
```

I get the following error:

```
A dependency job for postgresql@12-osm_psql_db.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that stumbles upon the same issue... I tracked the problem down to the *.service file referencing the wrong mount point for the database cluster location. Here's what I did:

Enable the new service (not sure if this is needed, but what the heck...)

```
sudo systemctl enable postgresql@12-osm_psql_db
```

Edit the postgresql@12-osm_psql_db.service

```
sudo systemctl edit --full postgresql@12-osm_psql_db.service
```

Change

```
RequiresMountsFor=/etc/postgresql/%I /var/lib/postgresql/%I
```

To

```
RequiresMountsFor=/etc/postgresql/%I /var/lib/postgresql/12/2TB1/osm_psql_db
```

As part of the service script, `%I` expands to `VERSION/CLUSTER` which in my case would have been `12/osm_psql_db`. Since I was choosing to place the DB on another SSD and the database can't reside in the root directory of a disk, the mount location in the *.service file needed to be updated to `12/2TB1/osm_psql_db`. This would not be necessary if you were storing all your databases on a single hard disk.